# Yii2 Invalid JSON data. when do validation another function

Tags: json, validation, yii2

all
Yii2 version 2.0.15.1
php  7.0.27

I don't know why this error happen.
I recheck this error : Invalid JSON data, it will come out only when do a valiation function checkAva.

here my code

MyModel.php

```
public function rules(){
    return [
     [['docs'],'file','maxFiles'=>10,'skipOnEmpty'=>true],
     [['available'], 'checkAva','skipOnEmpty' => true,'on'=>'create'],] // if this validation activated error will come out 
}
```

function checkAva

```
public function checkAva($attribute, $params)
    {
        $caid = $this->budget_id;
        $available  = Budget::find()
                ->select(['available'])
                ->where('id = :caid', [':caid' => $caid])
                ->one();
        if ($this->available != $available->available){
         $this->addError('available', 'pls change');
        }
    }
```

function initialPreview

```
public function initialPreview($data,$field,$type='file'){
        $initial = [];
        $files = Json::decode($data);
        if(is_array($files)){
            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                if($type=='file'){
                    $initial[] = "<div class='file-preview-other'><h2><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></i></h2></div>";
                }elseif($type=='config'){
                    $initial[] = [
                        'caption'=> $value,
                        'width'  => '1200px',
                        'url'    => Url::to(['/memo/deletefile','id'=>$this->id,'fileName'=>$key,'field'=>$field]),
                        'key'    => $key
                    ];
                }
                else{
                    $initial[] = Html::img(self::getUploadUrl().$this->ref.'/'.$value,['class'=>'file-preview-image', 'alt'=>$model->file_name, 'title'=>$model->file_name]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $initial;
    }
```

_form

```
use yii\helpers\Json;
use kartik\widgets\FileInput;
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'docs[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                        'options' => [
                            //'accept' => 'image/*',
                            'multiple' => true
                        ],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                           'initialPreview'=>$model->initialPreview($model->docs,'docs[]','file'),  // if comment this code no error come out I thing it something about formatter?
                           'initialPreviewConfig'=>$model->initialPreview($model->docs,'docs','config'), // if comment this code no error come out I thing it something about formatter?
                            'allowedFileExtensions'=>['pdf','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','jpeg','png','jpg','txt','rtf','tiff','tif'],
                            'initialPreviewAsData'=>true,
                            'maxFileSize'=>15000,
                            'showPreview' => true,
                            'showCaption' => true,
                            'showRemove' => true,
                            'showUpload' => false,
                            'overwriteInitial'=>true
                         ]
                        ]); ?>
```

in controller $model->docs will call uploadMultipleFile

```
  public function actionCreate()
     {

    $model->docs = $this->uploadMultipleFile($model);
     }


private function uploadMultipleFile($model,$tempFile=null){
             $files = [];
             $json = '';
             $tempFile = Json::decode($tempFile);
             $UploadedFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'docs');
             if($UploadedFiles!==null){
                foreach ($UploadedFiles as $file) {
                    try {   $oldFileName = $file->basename.'.'.$file->extension;
                            $newFileName = md5($file->basename.time()).'.'.$file->extension;
                            $file->saveAs(Memoopex::UPLOAD_FOLDER.'/'.$model->ref.'/'.$newFileName);
                            $files[$newFileName] = $oldFileName ;
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        //
                    }
                }
                $json = json::encode(ArrayHelper::merge($tempFile,$files));
             }else{
                $json = $tempFile;
             }
            return $json;
    }
```

error screen
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `JSON` data when you are decoding using `JSON::decode()` so your line

```
'initialPreview'=>$model->initialPreview($model->docs,'docs[]','file'),
```

is sending the parameter `$model->docs` which needs to be a valid `json` as you are decoding it inside your function `initialPreview()`

```
 $files = Json::decode($data);
```

`$data` isn't a valid `JSON` in your case make sure you have a valid JSON string and it will work.

Comment: so I put  `Json::encode` in my _from
I don't sure that a correct way or not but working.

`'initialPreview' => $model->initialPreview($model->docs = Json::encode($model->docs),'docs','file'),
                        'initialPreviewConfig' => $model->initialPreview($model->docs = Json::encode($model->docs),'docs','config'),`


thank you,sir

Comment: you can just pass `Json::encode($model->docs)` in the parameter @ChonjaroenChauynoo